# Изменить wp_terms_checklist() на странице настроек плагина

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На странице настроек плагина использую wp_terms_checklist() для вывода списка категорий с чекбоксами.

```
function plugin_settings(){
    register_setting( 'option_group', 'option_name', 'sanitize_callback' );

    add_settings_section( 'section_id', 'Основные настройки', '', 'primer_page' ); 

    add_settings_field('primer_field3', '', 'fill_primer_field3', 'primer_page', 'section_id' );

}

function fill_primer_field3(){
$post_id = -1; 
$args = array(
    'descendants_and_self' => 0,
    'selected_cats'        => false,
    'popular_cats'         => false,
    //'walker'               => new Walker_Custom_Term_List(),
    'taxonomy'             => 'category',
    'checked_ontop'        => true,
    'echo'                 => true,
);

wp_terms_checklist(0,$args);
}
```

При сохранении значения не сохраняет и не ставится чек. Я так понимаю надо изменить name у чекбокса и вставить checked. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Третий аргумент `register_setting()` задан неправильно. Там должен быть массив параметров. Если параметры не нужны, третий аргумент можно опустить. Возможно, в этом причина.

Comment: Такая запись до сих пор поддерживается. На всякий убрал,проверил, проблема осталась.

Comment: Значит, проблема не в этом, но такая запись не поддерживается. Посмотрите исходный код или документацию на kama - в третьем аргументе должен быть массив. По умолчанию - пустой массив.

Comment: Он же и пишет, что такой вариант рабочий, да и я проверил тоже. Суть не в этом вообщем.